# bias adjusted confidence interval for correlation coefficient

Tags: correlation, confidence-interval, stata, bias, sas

I stumbled across confidence intervals for $\rho$ in a statistics textbook. This was not part of the class, but I found it interesting. My textbook has a formula for this with a Fisher transformation, but says it's only valid when $n$ is large.

The reason it's only valid when $n$ is large is that it does not use the bias correction of $\frac{\rho}{2(n-1)}$. When $n$ is large, this is negligible, but when $n$ is small it is not. I found that for my purposes, even when $n$ is about 10 this does not really matter practically, but I was interested in how to properly calculate this anyway.

I found two statistics programs that implement this confidence interval with bias correction. I don't have access to either program, but their instructions were clear.

#### SAS

The documentation for SAS is [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/68142/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_corr_details11.htm).

They calculate the left limit for the 95% confidence interval as follows (I use 1.96 for the z-value for easier reading, and only calculate the left limit of the two-sided interval):

$\mathrm{tanh}(\mathrm{arctanh}(r) - \frac{r}{2(n-1)} - \frac{1.96}{\sqrt{n-3}})$

There are examples on [this page](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/63104/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_corr_sect030.htm). I verified (using python/numpy) that the SAS output in the screenshot (Output 2.3.2) matches this formula.

```
from numpy import tanh, arctanh, sqrt
r = -0.86843
n = 28
tanh(arctanh(r)-r/(2*(n-1)) - 1.96/sqrt(n-3))
> -0.9357293430819933
```

#### Stata

For Stata, I found [this journal article](https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0041).
They use a bias of $2\rho/(n-1)$ (page 12 of the pdf, page number 422).

Their formula for the left limit of a 95% confidence interval is:

$\mathrm{tanh}(\mathrm{arctanh}(r) - \frac{2r}{n-1} -  \frac{1.96}{\sqrt{n-3}})$

I verified their formula with their example as well:

```
r = -0.629
n = 20
tanh(arctanh(r) - (2*r)/(n-1) - 1.96/sqrt(n-3))
> -0.8173956732664086
```

Obviously, if I use the SAS method with these values, the result is different:

```
tanh(arctanh(r)-r/(2*(n-1)) - 1.96/sqrt(n-3))
> -0.8332200380924147
```

Without using any correction, the result is:

```
tanh(arctanh(r)- 1.96/sqrt(n-3))
> -0.8382116123893466
```

​
So, even though the difference between the SAS way and the Stata way is small, when compared to not applying a correction at all, the difference is relatively large. The SAS result is much closer to the result without correction than the Stata result.

### Fisher

I then figured I would check the sources that the Stata article cites. [This](https://digital.library.adelaide.edu.au/dspace/bitstream/2440/15169/1/14.pdf) is a reference cited for the Fisher correction. The math is way above my head, but I could follow the example tables. The table on page 15 (pdf page 14) has an example with $r=0.6, n=25$. Fisher gives quartile limits of $[0.4905,0.6774]$

That is exactly the same result as the SAS formula gives (I assume the tiny difference is rounding error):

```
r = 0.6
n = 25
z = st.norm.ppf(0.75) 
tanh(arctanh(r) - r/(2*(n-1)) - z/sqrt(n-3)), tanh(arctanh(r) - r/(2*(n-1)) + z/sqrt(n-3)) 
> (0.49059640289891715, 0.6774840469502461)
```

### Question

Are both methods considered correct? I know (now) that there are other formula's to correct for this bias as well, but in this case, both are applying Fisher's correction, but one has 2 in the numerator, the other 2 in the denominator.

If there are statistics textbooks that go into these details, and possibly some history, (but are accessible for people who only have undergraduate math knowledge), I would be interested in that as well.

Comment: Interim report: I am the author of the _Stata Journal_ article cited and will check the paper and program as soon as possible.